# Unrecognized keyword. (near REGEXP)

Tags: mysql, sql

I am watching tutorials and trying to learn something more about MySQL. Everything worked fine until I encountered a problem where, for some reason, I can't use REGEXP. When I type it in, I get "Unrecognized keyword. (near REGEXP)". This is what I'm trying to achieve -

```
SELECT name FROM items WHERE name REGEXP '.boxes'
```

This is the error I get:

Static analysis:

2 errors were found during analysis.

Unrecognized keyword. (near "REGEXP" at position 34)
Unexpected token. (near "'.boxes'" at position 41)
SQL query: Documentation

SELECT name FROM items WHERE name REGEXP '.boxes' LIMIT 0, 25

MySQL said: Documentation

## 1139 - Got error 'this version of PCRE is compiled without UTF support at offset 0' from regexp

Comment: Strange. But your statement is correct, I just tried it with a sample table (just to assure you, although it doesn't really help you).

Comment: Hmm no idea why it doesn't work. Thank you though!

Comment: did you got the solution ? I am facing this issue too

Comment: Unfortunately, no. :(

Comment: Try using `RLIKE` instead of `REGEXP`. `SELECT name FROM items WHERE name RLIKE '.boxes' `